# How do I retrieve values from NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am new to this.
I have parsed 10 values from a website to a tableview and linked to a detail view controller.
How do I get the individual value to show when tapped on the each cells?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[self tableView]setDelegate:self];
    [[self tableView]setDataSource:self];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    [array removeAllObjects];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    } 



-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *feed = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];
    NSArray *arrayOfEntry = [feed objectForKey:@"entry"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry){
        NSDictionary *title = [diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *label = [title objectForKey:@"label"];

        [array addObject:label];


    }
    [[self tableView] reloadData];

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "get each value from the table"?

Comment: do you want to print key and values?

Comment: Can you add json output received from webservice to your question? That way it would be lot easier to help you out...

Answer (score 0):

JSON data would be in `NSMutableArray` format.

```
NSMutableArray *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

int i=0;
for (i=0;i<[allDataDictionary count];i++) {
    NSLog("value is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[allDataDictionary objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"yourKey"]];)
}
```